# How to change thumbnail size without Command + J

Tags: keyboard, finder, macos, mouse

On my mac (`macOS 10.12.6`) I can't find a quick way to resize image thumbnails in **icon view** mode.

I remember many years ago, with **Leopard**, by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Up/Down</kbd> it was possible to resize thumbnails.

Is there any way to use that functionality or third-party software that enables this functionality in **Sierra**?

I am using a normal keyboard and a normal optical mouse. Not a Magic Keyboard or a Magic Mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming you also don’t have a trackpad,  so the easiest option would probably be to make sure you enable the Status Bar in Finder and then you can just **use the slider at the bottom right of any Finder window**.

To enable the Status Bar, go to View > Show Status Bar.

Answer (score 0):

On Mojave (`macOS 10.14.4`) I bumped into this, because I have discovered such a shortcut by mistake.

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to decrease thumbnail size
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> to increase thumbnail size

[image: small thumbnails]

[image: big thumbnails]

### Later Edit:

This works also in "Galery" View, it's very useful for picture folders, however sometimes the text / pics are overlapping:

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to decrease thumbnail size

[image: small thumbnails]

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> to increase thumbnail size

[image: big thumbnails]

Comment: Wow, and in Icon/Galery Mode (the first button in the bar) it works same.

You can increase and decrease thumbnail size incrementally.

Woow, cool feat for my photo folders.